# Comparing two text files and printing out matching ids, sub_ids and timestamp related to the id

Tags: perl

I found this solution in Perl interesting. I have a similar situation to print matching columns and two additional columns from the second file (Rev ID n date released). How do I read both files from this code. I am planning to dissect this code and learn hashing and arrays from this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# create names lookup table from first file
  my %names;
  while (<>) {
  (my $col1)= split / /, $_;
  $names{$col1} = 1;
  last if eof;
  }

# scan second file
  while (<>) {
  print if /^(\S+).*/ && not $names{$1};
  }

 File 1:
 Name               IRR ID
 slic73p1hsicbxttop 99034438
 c73p1avrsrldo150top99034238
 c73p1avrfusevrmtop 99034201

 Example file 2
 Type Name              Rev ID   IRR ID   PP Group      Date Released  PP Category                              
 Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_5 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 5/3/2015 6:59   Hard   
 Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_4 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 4/23/2015 10:27 Hard   
 Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_3 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 3/17/2015 23:51 Hard   
 Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_2 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 2/1/2015 11:27  Hard   

 Expected Output: there are also other rows in the table which doesn't match
 IRR ID   Rev ID   Date Released (date to be printed in a chronological   order)
 99034201 PROD_2_5 5/3/2015 6:59    
 99034201 PROD_2_4 4/23/2015 10:27  
 99034201 PROD_2_3 3/17/2015 23:51  
 99034201 PROD_2_2 2/1/2015 11:27
```

Answer (score 0):

First chunk:

```
my %names;
while (<>) {
    ( my $col1 ) = split / /, $_;
    $names{$col1} = 1;
    last if eof;
}
```

- We declare a hash called `names`.
- We cycle through a filehandle, one line at a time. This file handle is `<>` which has a special meaning in perl - it's *either* `STDIN` or the contents of the files specified on the command line. It looks like this code only works in the latter case, which is generally bad form.
- In each loop iteration, `$_` is set to the current line.
- `$_` is `split` on whitespace, which turns it into an array.
- `my ( $col1 )` is an array - the first element out of the split is assigned to `$col1`. (You could assign the rest with `my ( $col1, $col2, @more_cols ) = ...` )
- The key `$col1` in the `names` hash is set to 1.

E.g.:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c73p1avrsrldo150top' => 1,
          'c73p1avrfusevrmtop' => 1,
          'slic73p1hsicbxttop' => 1
        };
```

Then we start on the second file:

```
  while (<>) {
      print if /^(\S+).*/ && not $names{$1};
  }
```

Starts with a bad regular expression that 'just' captures the first word on the line (into $1). And if `$names{$1}` *isn't* set, will print the line.

Which given your input data is simply not going to work - because you're checking if `Comp` is present in `names` and it won't be.